# How to make Magento understand we are on the subdomain?

Tags: magento, cookies

Need your help. I made a multi-view (domain.com & sub.domain.com) store with Magento 1.9.2.1. Everything is fine! But! When you try to get the subdomain, magento show you information from the main domain.
On the other side when you try to get subdomain through the main domain (language switcher with GET "?___store=viewSubDomainCode&___from_store=viewDomainCode").
The reason is in setting Cookies I suppose.
How to make Magento set cookies when my request is directly http://sub.domain.com.
Index.php of subdomain:

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'code of my WEBSITE';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Important thing: I need one COOKIES for both domains (one cart).

Simply say: **I want to set CurrentStore of subdomain!**

Answer (score 0):

First of, you need to set your cookies correctly to make them work in domain/subdomain:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68070/whats-the-correct-cookie-config-for-a-magento-site-split-across-multiple-instan

Regarding the store switching to the correct view, you need either .htaccess modification:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:domain1_com]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:domain2_com]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

Or modify index.php to switch based on domain:

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'domain1.com':
    case 'www.domain1.com':
        $mageRunCode = 'domain1_com';
        $mageRunType = 'website';
    break;
    case 'domain2.com':
    case 'www.domain2.com':
        $mageRunCode = 'domain2_com';
        $mageRunType = 'website';
    break;
}
```

With this, don't forget to clear cache & sessions, it should work.